# How to calculate inception score in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to test if my GAN implemented by TensorFlow 2.0 can reproduce the results in the papers. However, all the available evaluation metrics are based on TensorFlow 1.X or Pytorch. And some operations like placeholder, session is incompatible in 2.0 version. Could anyone help, please?